# Pick out k maximal elements of a array/list

Tags: python, arrays, list

Say I have an array or a list, for example L as in the following. Now I want to pick out the k maximal elements out of L (here k = 4) such that none of the picked out elements repeats. The following code accomplishes picking out the maximal elements, but with repetitions. What do I have to change? I have tried a few variants with if-statements, also another inbuilt for-loop, but am unable at the moment to find something that works.

```
L = [2,4,4,5,3]
Y = np.zeros(5)

for j in range(4):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        M = max(L)
        if L[i] == M:
            Y[i] = M
            L[i] = 0
            break

print(L)
print(Y)
```

Output:

```
[2, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[0., 4., 4., 5., 3.]
```

I would like the order to stay the same, whilst also requiring the number of elements in the list/array to stay the same. So in this case, what I want in the end is the following output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[2., 4., 0., 5., 3.]
```

Comment: remove duplicates first, then pick k?

Comment: Maybe changing L to a set, but then the order won’t be maintained.

Comment: Do you know about [Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)?

Comment: Any time you want to remove duplicates in Python, either use a set or a hash table (dictionary). A dictionary would let you keep counts of repeats, so that you could test on that condition.

Comment: Take k elements out of sorted set of your list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `k` max values and their corresponding indices skipping the next duplicates you can use

```
L = np.array([2,4,4,5,3])
k = 4

idx, values = [], []

for i in np.argsort(-L):
  if L[i] not in values:
    values.append(L[i])
    idx.append(i)
    if len(idx) == k:
      break
print (idx, values)
```

Output:

```
[3, 1, 4, 0] [5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Now to frame it as the expected you can use

```
result = np.zeros(len(L))
result[idx] = L[idx]
print (result)
```

Output:

```
[2. 4. 0. 5. 3.]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = sorted(list(set([2, 4, 4, 5, 3])))[:K]
```

What this does:

- creates a set from the list of elements. A set is a collection with only unique elements
- turns the set into a list so we can sort it
- sorts the list
- [:K] takes the last K elements from the list

Comment: Is it possible to retrace where the now sorted maximal elements of the list were before the sorting? I mean, I would like to have the information about the position of each of the picked out maximal elements in the unsorted version of L.

Comment: No it’s not possible with just what I put here, there are ways to do that though. What if a maximal element is duplicated in the list? Do you need both positions or just one?